# Find the largest integer less than 8000

Tags: least-common-multiple

Is there a simple way to solve the problem?

> Find the largest integer less than 8000 which leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: $7561{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $N$ leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $2,3,4,5,6,7$. This happens if and only if $2,3,4,5,6,7$ all divide $N-1$, which happens if and only if their least common multiple, $420$ divides $N-1$.

Therefore $N=420k+1$. It is easy to check the largest multiple of $420$ under $8000$ is $420\times 19=7980$. So the largest value for $N$ is $7981$

Comment: It is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, **8 and 9**.

Comment: @kennytm: I imagine Carry on Smiling simplified the problem in order to leave something for the OP to do.

Comment: sure, lets go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Review the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  Clearly $1$ leaves the proper remainder.  What is the next number that does?